# Cannot add Vertical Divider to TableLayout Android

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, tablelayout, android-tablelayout

I want to add verdical divider to my `TableLayout`.

My `TableLayout` looks like this:

[image: Table Layout]

But i want to add a line (divider) between two `textview`s in each row. I have tried placing a `View` between two `textview`s but it stretches the row.

Here is my code for the above layout:

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/row"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:showDividers="beginning"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:stretchColumns="1"
android:background="@drawable/custom_background">

<TableRow>
    <TextView
        android:text="Name"
        android:padding="3dip" />

    <TextView
        android:text="Imran"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:padding="3dip" />
</TableRow>

<View
    android:layout_height="2dip"
    android:background="#FF909090" />

<TableRow>
    <TextView
        android:text="Name"
        android:padding="3dip" />

    <TextView
        android:text="Test"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:padding="3dip" />
</TableRow>

<View
    android:layout_height="2dip"
    android:background="#FF909090" />

<TableRow>
    <TextView
        android:text="Name"
        android:padding="3dip" />

    <TextView
        android:text="Test"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:padding="3dip" />
</TableRow>
```

I want to achieve the following layout:

[image: Table Layout]

Can anyone help me achieve the above layout using `TableLayout` or any other way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the main xml file. You can use

```
    android:divider="@drawable/vertical_divider"
    android:showDividers="middle"
```

to display vertical divider in Linear layout. I have designed your layout, I don't like Table layout, You can try Linear layouts.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner"
android:orientation="vertical">


 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:orientation="horizontal"
     android:divider="@drawable/vertical_divider"
    android:showDividers="middle">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:text="Lorem ipsum" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:text="Lorem ipsum" />
   </LinearLayout>

<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:background="#FFCCCCCC"></View>

  <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:divider="@drawable/vertical_divider"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:showDividers="middle">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:text="Lorem ipsum" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:text="Lorem ipsum" />
   </LinearLayout>

<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:background="#FFCCCCCC"></View>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:divider="@drawable/vertical_divider"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:showDividers="middle">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:text="Lorem ipsum" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:text="Lorem ipsum" />
   </LinearLayout>

   <View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:background="#FFCCCCCC"></View>

  </LinearLayout>
```

Here is the code of

rounded_corner.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

  <solid android:color="#00000000" />
  <stroke
    android:width="1dp"
    android:color="#bababa" />

  <padding
    android:bottom="1dp"
    android:left="1dp"
    android:right="1dp"
    android:top="1dp" />

  <corners
    android:bottomLeftRadius="25dip"
    android:bottomRightRadius="25dip"
    android:topLeftRadius="25dip"
    android:topRightRadius="25dip" />
  </shape>
```

Here is the code of

```
vertical_divider.xml

   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <inset xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:insetBottom="2dp"
   android:insetTop="2dp">
   <shape>
      <size android:width="1dp" />
      <solid android:color="#FFCCCCCC" />
   </shape>
  </inset>
```

Place your color codes above :)

Output

[image]

Comment: Thanks for helping me out but i need the divider right next to the first textview not in the middle. How can i do that?
I have tried android:showdividers="beginning" but it is still showing the vertical divider in the middle.

Comment: Dear play with weight of textview. try weight 1.5 and 0.5,

Comment: Add weightSum in inner layouts having horizontal orientation and change weight of textviews according to this code.
<LinearLayout
        android:weightSum="2"
        android:showDividers="middle">

        <TextView
            android:layout_weight="0.7" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_weight="1.3" />
    </LinearLayout>

Answer (score 4):

I think this solution is much easier.

Your TableLayout:

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:divider="@drawable/table_divider"
    android:showDividers="middle"
    android:shrinkColumns="*"
    android:background="@drawable/rounded_corners">

    <TableRow
        android:divider="@drawable/table_divider"
        android:showDividers="middle"
        android:weightSum="3">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:padding="3dp"
            android:text="Column1"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:padding="3dp"
            android:text="Column2"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:padding="3dp"
            android:text="Column3"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:divider="@drawable/table_divider"
        android:showDividers="middle"
        android:weightSum="3">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:padding="3dp"
            android:text="Column1" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:padding="3dp"
            android:text="Column2" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:padding="3dp"
            android:text="Column3" />
    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

Your background drawable:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<solid android:color="#00000000" />
<stroke
    android:width="1dp"
    android:color="@android:color/black" />

<corners
    android:bottomLeftRadius="10dp"
    android:bottomRightRadius="10dp"
    android:topLeftRadius="10dp"
    android:topRightRadius="10dp" />
```

And the shape for your dividers:

```
table_divider.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <size android:height="1dp" />
    <size android:width="1dp" />
    <solid android:color="@android:color/black" />
</shape>
```

Result:

[image: Result]

If you do not need a background, you can do this in your TableLayout and in every TableRow:

```
android:showDividers="beginning|middle|end"
```

Result without the background:

[image: Result without the background]