# Table format not displaying in android for below layout

Tags: android, layout

Hi in the below code I am displaying a table layout to display the table rows in table layout.

Each row separated with line want to display after username want to display line and then email want to display line.
Can any one help me how to add the vertical line to separate the each row.

please check the below code and let me know

[![In the below screen describes the I want to add each row separated with line .like row][1]][1]

```
[![<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/realmsbg">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:background="@drawable/layout_border">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/manage_operator"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:padding="12dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/layout_border"
                    android:textColor="#fff"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Manage Operator List"/>



                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TableLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent">
                        <TableRow
                            android:background="@color/color_gray"
                            android:padding="@dimen/dimen_8dp">
                            <TextView
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_weight="1"
                                android:text="Username"
                                android:id="@+id/txtRank"
                                android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
                            <TextView
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_weight="1"
                                android:text="Email"
                                android:id="@+id/txtMovieName"
                                android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
                            <TextView
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_weight="1"
                                android:text="Mobile"
                                android:id="@+id/txtYear"
                                android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
                        </TableRow>


                    </TableLayout>
                    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                        android:id="@+id/my_recycler_view"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_margin="5dp"
                        android:divider="@null"
                        android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
                        />
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/empty_view"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="No Records"
                        android:visibility="gone" />


                </LinearLayout>


        </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>][1]][1]
```

Comment: `TableRow`s are just specialized horizontal `LinearLayout`s, so you can use the `android:divider` and `android:showDividers` attributes to add those, like is shown in these answers: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42902432, https://stackoverflow.com/a/53592162.

Answer (score 0):

Your main activity layout XML file and your item layout XML file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/llHeader"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
            android:background="@android:color/black"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/_8sdp"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/_8sdp"
            android:weightSum="3">

        <TextView
                style="@style/textBlackBold"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Username" />

        <TextView
                style="@style/textBlackBold"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Email" />

        <TextView
                style="@style/textBlackBold"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Mobile" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerDayAttendance"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_above="@+id/llTotal"
            android:layout_below="@+id/view1" />
</LinearLayout>
```